# React Native - How to setState inside the function statement?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using a external package of react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box and react-native-navigation v2.

I'm using the console log to know if the user is enabled the GPS or not. So I want to do is when the user is enabled or already enabled the GPS I want to navigate it to the AuthScreen.

This is what I see in the `console.log` but I do not know how to access it to return a statement. :

React Native Debugger:

```
Object {alreadyEnabled: false, enabled: true, status: "enabled"}
```

The question is how can I access the `alreadyEnabled`, `enabled` or `status` if the user is enabled the GPS then navigate it to the next screen which is the AuthScreen then, if the user didn't enable the GPS it forcely to close the App or return something to make the enable the GPS again?

Here is the code:

```
gpsLocation = () => {
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
    message: "<h2>Use Location?</h2> \
    This app wants to change your device settings:<br/><br/>\
    Use GPS for location<br/><br/>",
    ok: "Yes",
    cancel: "No",
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#4f6d7a',
      positiveButtonTextColor: '#000000',
      negativeButtonTextColor: '#000000'
    },
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    showDialog: true,
    openLocationServices: true,
    preventOutSideTouch: true,
    preventBackClick: true,
    providerListener: true
  }).then(function(success) {
    console.log(success)
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
};

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('locationProviderStatusChange', function(status) {
  console.log(status);
});
};
```

UPDATE: I already know how to access it in the React Native Debugger or `console.log`
Now, my question is how to use `setState`inside the `function` statement?
I already use the `setState` inside the `function` but it says in the React Native Debugger or `console.log` is "`thisSetState is not a function"`.

```
  gpsLocation = () => {
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
    message: "<h2>Use Location?</h2> \
    This app wants to change your device settings:<br/><br/>\
    Use GPS for location<br/><br/>",
    ok: "Yes",
    cancel: "No",
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#4f6d7a',
      positiveButtonTextColor: '#000000',
      negativeButtonTextColor: '#000000'
    },
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    showDialog: true,
    openLocationServices: true,
    preventOutSideTouch: true,
    preventBackClick: true,
    providerListener: true
  }).then(function(success) {
    console.log(success)
    if(success.status == "enabled"){
      alert("enabled")
     //How to setState here?
    } else {
      alert("LOL");
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
};

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('locationProviderStatusChange', function(status) {
  console.log(status);
});
```

};

Comment: Try arrow functions in `then` statement. i mean something like this: `.then((success) => {    }) `

Comment: happy to hear this!